# What is the best way to display IRC Server/Channel list?

Tags: interface-design

I'm trying to design a smart way to manage the Server/Channel List. I want to do something different that'll be simple for users to use. I had thought of Modifying tab controls to have a "parent" (IRC Server) and children(Channels Queries). Where the children reside INSIDE the parent, however this isn't very good for space design purposes.

The typical design is just to do a bunch of tabs or a long TreeView list.

I'm wanting to design something that is easy for anyone to use, but advanced enough to show everything you need.

What would your suggestions be?

This is basically what I had in mind, not exactly but you should be able to get the idea:
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a mega dropdown menu: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/ Then you could have multiple columns inside the dropdown, and keep it easy-to-use.

Comment: Hm.. I think that's sparked a few ideas. Thanks :)